# Custom UITableViewCell is reloaded with new data but not drawn with new data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, redraw

I have a custom uitableviewcell with the following structure

```
customCell
  Content View
    vertical Stack View
      title Label
      horizontal Stack View
        Label
        Label
      horizontal Stack View
        Label
        Label
```

On tap there is a segue to a detail view controller. When coming back, I reload the tableView in main task.

I see the following happen:

A. no problem:

1. table view is empty, I press the add button
2. detail editor opens, edit the data for all labels
3. go back to the UITableView
4. -> draws everything -> no problem.
5. redraws with new data when editing the corresponding content.

B. Problem

1. table view is empty, I press the add button
2. detail editor opens, edit data for the first 3 labels, not for the bottom 2 labels
3. go back to the UITableView
4. -> draws edited Labels, adjusts layout so that the bottom horizontal stack view takes no space
5. go to detail editor again for the same cell, add text for the bottom 2 labels
6. go back to the table view controller
7. -> Problem: bottom Line is still not drawn
8. But the debugger shows that the cell is rendered and the data is available and the label texts are set

I call reloadData() in main thread. Not doing so is often the cause of missing updates of UITableViewCells. Not in this case.

-> I have a workaround, see my answer below. Applying this workaround solves the problem.

**Edit as asked:**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(workoutCellIdentifier2, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WorkoutTableViewCell
    let workout = appDelegate.persistence.workouts[indexPath.row]
    cell.setWorkout(workout, healthData: appDelegate.healthData)
    return cell
}
```

It never goes to the fallback path

Comment: Can you show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: And your `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. And have you considered putting the two stack views in a vertical stack view and then hiding/unhiding the lower horizontal stack view as required

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Comment: hiding/unhiding is not required. It is done automagically by some Apple code. This is the cause of the problem.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` never returns nil, so no it will never take the fallback path.  Are you properly reconfiguring the cell in `setWorkout` or in `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: it never returns nil, but `as?` can make it to nil. Ich checked in the debugger and used `print ("\(label.text)")` to make sure the text is there. It was.

Comment: As? Will only make it nil if you haven't matched your reuseIdentifier to your custom cell class. In fact in this case you should probably use as! because you want an exception if the downcast fails as it means you have a mistake

Comment: I understand and I am aware of this and will change as? to as!. It is not related to what happened here.

Comment: changed the code here and in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I appears the layout process of the cell optimizes away the bottom line when it contains empty labels (text == nil)

The first two lines get more vertical space.

When the label texts are set later, the layout process doesn't reverse. `setNeedsLayout()` doesn't help. So the bottom line is still optimized away even though it contains data now when redrawing.

Workaround:

Never set the label text to nil in the cell. Set it to " " when no data is available.

Now the the bottom line is never optimized away. An empty space remains that indicates that there is something not set yet.